# trouble accessing a global variable

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, error-handling

This is my code:

```
function Todo(id, task, who, dueDate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.task = task;
    this.who = who;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.done = false;
}

var todos = new Array();

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    submitButton.onclick = getFormData;
    var searchButton = document.getElementById("button");
    searchButton.onclick = search;       
}


//function to add todo items to the todos array

function search() {
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.legnth; i++) {
     var todoObj = todos[i];
     console.log(todoObj[0]);
    }
}
```

This is not all of my code, but the last function is where I am having trouble. I can't seem to access the global todos array. I've tried passing it as a parameter to the search function. I've tried even doing i < window.todos.length. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try changing legnth to length.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a typo.

Replace

```
todos.legnth
```

with

```
todos.length
```